# Dynamic Row Group RDLC Report

Tags: c#, xml, dataset, rdlc

Suppose I have a list of employee who are working in different organization department. Like... Plan=>Department=>Section or Unit =>Department=>Section or Department=>Section. I need to group them according to organization department.
Sometime data would be like...

```
**Unit  Department  Section Employee**
Unit-1  Depart-1    Section-1   James
Unit-1  Depart-2    Section-3   Rock
Unit-1  Depart-2    Section-4   Ali
```

Or

```
**Plan  Department  Section Employee**
Plan -1 Depart-1    Section-1   James
Plan -1 Depart-2    Section-3   Rock
Plan -2 Depart-2    Section-4   Ali
```

Or

```
Department  Section Employee
Depart-1    Section-1   James
Depart-2    Section-3   Rock
Depart-2    Section-4   Ali
```

i.e Organization structure defined dynamically and Organization sequence defined dynamically.I need to create dynamic row group with dynamic column.
[image]

Comment: What does a "row group of employee list" look like?

Comment: This should be an html tag not an xml.  RDLC are html and can have queries into a sql database.